# Masked url method with Fancybox not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

**UPDATED: I seem to have fixed the problem in Chrome by adding in 'cache-control: Private' to headers in the get-image page (see updated code below with comments to show what I did). I am not experienced enought to understand why that would have fixed anything but removing that single header line brings the problem back on Chrome (and the cache-control response header in Chrome without that line is 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0').**

**It still isn't working in Safari. If the cache-control change gives someone an idea on why it's sitll not working in Safari, then I'd be very happy to hear about it!**

First time on Stack Overflow. Apologies if not doing this right.

I'm using Wordpress and the Easy Fancybox plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/) which uses Fancybox 1.3.6. (I have a question into the plugin author but I'm not certain it's related to the plugin.)

I’ve been trying to come up with a way to mask image urls and I thought I had it cracked but now I’ve found it doensn't work on Chrome and Safari.

You can see an example at http://www.jatest.dreamhosters.com/test-page/

On this page I have two examples of the same image. One fires up fancybox in the standard way, while the other uses the new hidden url approach.

The error in the Console on Chrome is 'Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html'. **UPDATE: fixed this warning by adding in 'Content-Type: image' (as per the new version of get-image below) but this did not fix the problem in Chrome or Safari.**

Here’s how I’m doing the hidden url approach. (This is a sort of cut-down version to keep it simple, but this is exactly how it’s implemented on the test page example I’ve given.)

On the “test-page” I have the following code (with a `session_start()` further up the page):

```
<?php

$img_src = 'http://www.jatest.dreamhosters.com/wp-content/uploads/Choir-practice.jpg';

//deletes all session variables related to fancybox hidden urls
//only used to keep the number of session variables down
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $session_variable) {
    $locator = strpos( $key, 'rfhash' );
    if ( $locator > 0 ) { //if this session variable was created for fancybox hidden url (because it contains _rfhash)
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}

//create new session variable
$imageHash = '_rfhash'.md5(uniqid());
$_SESSION[$imageHash] = $img_src;

$hidden_img_src = add_query_arg('h', $imageHash, 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/get-image/');

?>

Unhidden url<br />
<a class = "fancybox" href = "<?php echo $img_src; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>" width = "700" height = "525">
</a>
<br />
Hidden url<br />
<a class = "fancybox {type: 'image'}" href = "<?php echo $hidden_img_src; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $hidden_img_src; ?>" width = "700" height = "525">
</a>
```

Then on the get-image page **(updated version)** that the “masked” url points to, I have:

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); //adding this got rid of a warning but didn't fix the problem
header('cache-control: Private'); //adding this fixed the problem in Chrome

if (isset($_GET['h'])) {
    $hash = $_GET['h'];

    if (isset($_SESSION[$hash]) && $_SESSION[$hash]) {

        readfile($_SESSION[$hash]); //changing from echo file_get_contents to readfile made no difference but from what I've come across seems to be recommended instead
        unset($_SESSION[$hash]);
    }
}
```

I'm now out of my depth and at a loss. Any suggestions would be really very welcome...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this `class="fancybox {type: 'image'}"` is a valid class. Why don't you add the option `type: 'image'` to your custom fancybox initialization script instead?

Comment: BTW, next time you give a link to a test page, make sure you remove the ANNOYING context menu.

Comment: @JFK re the class - that is how type: 'image' has to be added when using the fancybox plugin for wordpress. I know that's working OK as using that fixed another bug. Sorry about the context menu - you mean the disabling of the right click right? Re-enabled now...

Comment: Updated to reflect what seems to be a fix to the problem in Chrome - I just don't understand why it's a fix and it also hasn't fixed the problem in Safari

Comment: Thanks JFK that's definitely given me a clue. Interesting that on the test page all browsers do manage to load the image using the hidden url to display it as a normal img, and it's only on Safari that when you use the anchor tag and Fancybox as the trigger to get the image again is there a problem. But you're right - actually in all browsers using your test the url to get the image is failing to load, which I guess means the other browsers are somehow able to work around that when the load is triggered through the anchor tag and fancybox, whereas Safari isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So rather a silly error to make in the end, and thanks to JFK for putting me on the right track.

The problem was the `unset($_SESSION[$hash]);` in get-images. I think this is what was happening...

Test page would load, and get-images would run once to display the image on the test page (which it would do successfully) and then unset the session variable. Then when the link was clicked to trigger fancybox get-image would run again but this time the session variable wouldn't exist so the image would fail to load. However in Firefox, IE (and Chrome once I'd set cache-control to private) the browser would load the image from the cache. In Safari, it wouldn't.

Removing `unset($_SESSION[$hash]);` fixed the problem. I will need to use another method to keep the volume of session variables down.